# how to track the send email has read or deleted

Tags: php, phpmailer

Am sending mail to users via phpmailer, My requirement is to keep track of sent mail, (whomever opened mail, whomever deleted). I have mysql table to keep the track of sent mail. I need to update the flag mail_opened = 1 when the mail is opened and need to update the flag mail_deleted = 1.

Googled several times, still not getting any idea.
can some one help me to achieve this..

sorry for my bad English..

Comment: There is no reliable solution for this. Which actually is a good thing, since it is a clear breach of privacy.

Comment: You can insert a 1px image, backed by a PHP script to display a transparent GIF but also set `is_read` to `1` when accessed. You can pass a querystring variable. It's not very accurate, but it's about as close as you're going to get to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways at doing this.

You could use a SaaS such as [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) that support such feature already, or you could inject an HTTP request inside an image and process it.

For example: `<img src="http://domain.com/image.png?emailId={$emailId}&action=open">`

[You can found about injecting the request here.](http://www.phpdevtips.com/2013/06/email-open-tracking-with-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Are both SendGrid or MailChimp is free? Are both support opened and deleted status?

Comment: SendGrid offers a free plan limited to 12.000 emails/month. MailChimp is also free up to 2,000 subscribers and 12,000 emails/month. Deletes tracking I believe is not supported, however I think it's not even possible to do such a thing, however you can know if they opened the email, if they reported it as spam, or if it has bounced.

Comment: how can i integrate this in php?

Comment: You can use any library that has a driver support for either SendGrid or MailChimp. Or you could directly use [sendgrid-php](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php), if you're interested in SendGrid.

Comment: Mailchimp isn't free, it's ad-supported; there's a difference. SendGrid and Mailchimp are not the same kind of thing; Mailchimp's equivalent SMTP service is Mandrill, which is not free.

Comment: @Synchro Mandrill has shutdown its free package and it has been merged with MailChimp a couple of months ago as a paid add-on.

Comment: @GiamyPy how to use sendgrid? Normal image append method not worked with outlook mail. will sendGrid work for all mail?

Answer (score 0):

Spamers found multiple solutions for this. Tracking people secretly is not nice but possible.
The most common way is including an image into your email that is load from your server.

```
<img src="http://yourserver.com/track?id">
```

The image can be 1px * 1px and white, so the normal user wouldnt notice.

Comment: That's possible but will still not get all opened emails as many mail clients dont download the image